# ssh-add not persistent

Tags: deployment, ssh, capistrano

I am using `cap deploy`to deploy a ruby on rails application. Everything works fine so long as I execute `ssh-add`before that. If I don't, the command `cap deploy` asks for a password, because my authenticatable identification doesn't seem to be there anymore.

How can achieve not having to execute `ssh-add` before every `cap deploy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`ssh-agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent)

[Here](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) are some instructions to get it working